# How to use shell command result in perl script?

Tags: perl, shell

Can anyone show me, how to use shell command result in Perl script ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$whoami=`whoami`;
system ('cd /var/home/'.$whoami.'/htdocs');
print $whoami;
```

Script output

```
[user1@srv _1]$ ./sys.pl
sh: line 1: /htdocs: No such file or directory
user1
```

I want to change dir to /var/home/user1/htdocs

Comment: please note that none of the solutions (and your corrected code) will change the working directory of your program!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$whoiami=`whoami`;

print "$whoiami";

chomp $whoiami;
system ("cd /home/$whoiami/reports");

print $whoiami;
```

Answer (score 4):

`$whoami` contains the endline character `\n`, which causes your command string to look like:

```
cd /var/home/user1
/htdocs
```

You should use `chomp` to delete the trailing newline from `$whoami`:

```
my $whoami = `whoami`;
chomp $whoami;
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished w/o shelling out:

```
#!perl
my $dir = '/home/'.getlogin().'/htdocs';
chdir $dir;
```